# Question about streaming in an http request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just starting out with the "request" package for nodejs in NPM and am confused as to what streaming a response to a file stream means?

Below is the most basic example given in the docs: It says "You can stream any response to a file stream"

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

I believe it means to write the code from the request url to a file called dodle.png? I am just really confused and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means whatever data returned by that URL get written to that file. Writing to file starts immediately when the first byte of data received in a response using file write stream.